# jQuery Setting position of object dynamically?

Tags: jquery, css, position, css-position

Okay so I have a weird dilemma. When I get the position of an element and output it, I actually get the real coordinates of the object. Like so below:

```
var el = $('#element');

var position = el.position();

console.log(position);
```

The output given is something like:

```
Object { top=0, left=120}
```

Works well, but now if I set the object to **position:absolute**, I get a weird output. The code below is an example of what I'm doing.

```
var el = $('#element');

var position = el.position();

el.css({
    top: position.top + 'px',
    left: position.left + 'px',
    position: 'absolute'
});

console.log(position);
```

Now the output I get is something like the one below.

```
Object { top=0, left=0}
```

So it seems that the **position:absolute** is resetting the top and left.

My question is ... how can I go about setting the left and top positions of an object while setting it to **position:absolute** through jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/sbe3C/2/

UPDATE 2:
Okay as I commented below, the issue seems to be happening only when I try to set position absolute to an object inside an each() loop. I have a jsfiddle example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/geocalleo/atNFz/

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Try making your CSS position:absolute, top:0, left:0 then you will see it change on screen. Then make it absolute, top:20, left:20 in your CSS and the position should show that

Comment: The jsfiddle looks like it is working to me

Comment: Okay, so my new fiddle example here shows the issue. It's when it's wrapped in a each() loop - http://jsfiddle.net/geocalleo/atNFz/

Comment: Your latest fiddle show 8px and 8px for me, what browser are you in?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! The problem was that I needed to iterate the items from bottom to top direction. I got the answer from another [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477469/2146361).

So it now looks something like this

```
$($('body > div').get().reverse()).each
```

Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocalleo/atNFz/3/).